# PRIME on Wayland

Tags: gpu, wayland

Is there a way to get PRIME working on a Wayland powered display? I am using Arch Linux with Integrated Skylake Graphics as well as a mobile AMD card.

The instructions on the [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PRIME) rely on xrandr, however, it appears that under a Wayland server the provider commands of xrandr don't work.

Comment: Have this same problem!
Were you able to resolve?

Comment: @mhz I was not. I gave up on it.

Comment: i am investigating same issue.

Comment: It seems it requires weston, there is wayland specific code in https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/wayland/weston.git for a weston-gears. https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTQyNjI